# Plot the graph with two best response functions, Mathematica

Tags: plotting, simulation, mathematica-online

I have another doubt regarding Mathematica. This is probably another question that can be easily answered, but since I'm a beginner it's a while that I'm stuck.
Since I'm using Mathematica online, the operations cannot be very demanding, otherwise it gets ages to give the output. Hence, instead of plotting two best response functions automatically, I generated two tables containing few data. I should plot them in a unique graph, with "a" variable on the x-axis and "di" on the y-axis. This is the code that I used to build the numerical simulation of the model:

```
T1=Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]],{k,1,10000}];
T2=Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]],{k,1,10000}];
V0=Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,10]],{k,1,10000}];
vi[a_,di_,pr_,V0_,T1_,T2_]:=If[a*(V0+di)+(1-a)*(V0+T1+T2)-pr>0,V0+T1-pr,0];
Vi[a_,di_,pr_]:=Mean[Table[vi[a,di,pr,V0[[k]],T1[[k]],T2[[k]]],{k,1,10000}]];
DVi[a_,di_,pr_]:={a+30*(Vi[a*1.02,di,pr]-Vi[a*0.98,di,pr]),di,pr};
DDvi[T_]:=DVi@@T;
NestList[DDvi,{0.5,0.,0.5},30];
BRi[di_,pr_]:=Last[NestList[DDvi,{0.5,di,pr},30]];
vinf[a_,alfa_,teta_,di_,pr_,V0_,T1_,T2_]:=alfa*If[a*(V0+di)+(1-a)*(V0+T1+T2)-pr>0,teta,0]+(1-alfa)*If[a*(V0+di)+(1-a)*(V0+T1+T2)-pr>0,V0+T1-pr,0]-(1-alfa)*If[a*(V0+di)+(1-a)*(V0+T1+T2)-pr>0,a*(V0+di)+(1-a)*(V0+T1+T2)-pr,0];
Vinf[a_,alfa_,teta_,di_,pr_]:=Mean[Table[vinf[a,alfa,teta,di,pr,V0[[k]],T1[[k]],T2[[k]]],{k,1,10000}]];
DVinf[a_,alfa_,teta_,di_,pr_]:={a,alfa,teta,di+30*(Vinf[a,alfa,teta,di*1.02,pr]-Vinf[a,alfa,teta,di*0.98,pr]),pr};
DDvinf[Q_]:=DVinf@@Q;
NestList[DDvinf,{0.5,1,0.1,1,0.5},30];
BRinf[a_,alfa_,teta_,pr_]:=Last[NestList[DDvinf,{a,alfa,teta,0.01,pr},30]]
```

And these are the two tables I was thinking to use to get the graph (BRinf stands for "di", whereas BRi stands for "a"):

```
sdata=Table[BRinf[a,0.5,0.1,0.5],{a,0,1,0.1}];
rdata=Table[BRi[di,0.5],{di,0,10,0.1}]
```

Do you think this is a good idea? Are there better ways to plot the graph with the two best response functions?
Thank you in advance for your help